# Facebook Comments Plugin Count - the stats comment count header is not showing

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I added Facebook Comments to a WordPress blog. The comment box header (says x comments with a drop down arrow and an "add a comment" link) is not showing up. See the default comment box at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/.

I inserted the following after the opening body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1432741046964019";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And the following function to load comments if comments are open:

```
function sitc_load_facebook_comments() {
if ( comments_open() ) {
        echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="';
        echo get_permalink();
        echo '" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>';
    }
}
```

Not sure if there has to be over five comments in order for the header to show up?

Answer (score 0):

Use this tag. Found on the FB comment doc :)

```
<fb:comments-count href=yourURL></fb:comments-count>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I updated my question to hopefully be more clear. I'm referring to the header that says "x comments" with a drop down arrow.